# porting Apache Cayenne from oracle to postgreSQL

Tags: java, postgresql, cursor, data-mapping, apache-cayenne

I'm porting an existing Java project from Oracle 10 to PostgreSQL 9.1.8 (is this version actually supported from Cayenne?)

Something is wrong in OUT parameters when a cursor is returned.
Return type should be of

> types.OTHER

but it looks like as a null object.
No problem with OUT parameters when different from cursors.

This is a piece of my datamap, there is a call to a postgreSQL stored function ShowValidSource:

```
<procedure name="ShowValidSource" schema="voting_x">
    <procedure-parameter name="i_n_sourceid" type="BIGINT" direction="in" />    
    <procedure-parameter name="i_s_description" type="VARCHAR" direction="in" />
    <procedure-parameter name="i_n_active" type="BIGINT" direction="in" />
    <procedure-parameter name="cur_ref" type="OTHER" direction="out" />
    <procedure-parameter name="o_n_exitflag" type="BIGINT" direction="out" />
    <procedure-parameter name="o_s_exitmsg" type="VARCHAR" direction="out" />
</procedure>
<db-entity name="cur_ref">
    <db-attribute name="SOURCE_ID" type="DOUBLE" isPrimaryKey="true"  />
    <db-attribute name="DESCRIPTION" type="VARCHAR" />
    <db-attribute name="ACTIVE" type="DOUBLE" />
</db-entity>
<obj-entity name="SourceByDescription" readOnly="true" className="it.mxx.vote.dao.types.SourceByDescriptionImpl" dbEntityName="cur_ref">
    <obj-attribute name="sourceId" type="java.lang.Double" db-attribute-path="SOURCE_ID" />
    <obj-attribute name="description" type="java.lang.String" db-attribute-path="DESCRIPTION" />
    <obj-attribute name="active" type="java.lang.Double" db-attribute-path="ACTIVE" />
</obj-entity>
```

Here is my procedure declare:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION showvalidsource(IN i_n_sourceid bigint, IN i_s_description character varying, IN i_n_active bigint, OUT o_rc_source refcursor, OUT o_n_exitflag bigint, OUT o_s_exitmsg character varying)
  RETURNS record AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
  --
  V_S_Description varchar(255);
  V_N_Active      bigint;
  V_N_ExitFlag    bigint:= NULL;
  v_rc_source     refcursor := 'cur_ref';
  -- 
BEGIN
  --
  IF I_N_Active = -1 THEN
    V_N_Active := null;
  ELSE
    V_N_Active :=I_N_Active;
  END IF;
  --
  V_S_Description := trim(lower(I_S_Description));
  --
  BEGIN
    --
    IF coalesce(V_N_Active,0) IN (0,1) THEN
      NULL;
    ELSE
      --
      V_N_ExitFlag := -10;
      O_S_exitMsg  := 'WARNING! I_N_Active accepted values : 0, 1, -1, null';
      RAISE EXCEPTION USING MESSAGE =  O_S_exitMsg;    
      --
    END IF;
  END;
  --
  --    IF  V_N_SourceId IS NOT NULL THEN
  IF coalesce(I_N_SourceId, -1) <> -1 THEN
    --
          OPEN v_rc_source FOR
           SELECT  vsd.source_id,
                   vsd.description,
                   vsd.active
              FROM voting_system_detail vsd
            WHERE vsd.source_id   = I_N_SourceId
              AND vsd.Description = coalesce(V_S_Description, vsd.Description)
              AND vsd.active      = coalesce(V_N_Active, vsd.active)
            ORDER BY vsd.source_id;
    --
    o_rc_source    := v_rc_source;
    O_N_exitFlag   := 0;
    O_S_exitMsg    := 'Ok';
    --
  ELSE
    --
          OPEN v_rc_source FOR
            SELECT vsd.source_id,
                   vsd.description,
                   vsd.active
              FROM voting_system_detail vsd
            WHERE vsd.Description = coalesce(V_S_Description, vsd.Description)
              AND vsd.active      = coalesce(V_N_Active, vsd.active)
            ORDER BY vsd.source_id;
    --
    o_rc_source    := v_rc_source;    
    O_N_exitFlag   := 0;
    O_S_exitMsg    := 'Ok';
  --
  END IF;   --IF  V_N_SourceId IS NOT NULL THEN
  --
  EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
     O_N_exitFlag := coalesce(V_N_ExitFlag,-1);
     O_S_exitMsg  := SQLERRM;
     --
     OPEN v_rc_source FOR
            SELECT -1  source_id,
                   'x' description,
                   -1  active
             WHERE 1=2;
     o_rc_source    := v_rc_source;

  END;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION showvalidsource(bigint, character varying, bigint)
  OWNER TO dbvoting;
```

NOTE: this cursor by pg client returns more records in 3 column type `(SOURCE_ID double, DESCRIPTION varchar, ACTIVE double)`

What could be wrong? Thanks

Comment: Cayenne does support PG 9.1. This simpler fucntion with out params works in our unit tests: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/cayenne/main/trunk/framework/cayenne-jdk1.5-unpublished/src/test/resources/ddl/postgresql/create-out-sp.sql?view=markup Is the above the full body of the function in question? I'd like to create a test case with ref cursor to see what issues it might have.

Comment: Thanks! added full plpgsql. Stored function by Cayenne has Ok exit codes (OUT o_n_exitflag, OUT o_s_exitmsg). I'm in doubt about the name of OUT cursor Cayenne should expect. o_rc_source or cur_ref ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I simplified a function a bit to run it with Cayenne unit tests. The result of a select on 9.1 was the following DataRow:

```
{o_rc_source=org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4ResultSet@4bd27069, 
 o_s_exitmsg=Ok, 
 o_n_exitflag=11}
```

which seems like exactly what you'd expect, refcursor is there, accessible as a ResultSet. This was a trunk build of Cayenne (should be the same as 3.1 in respect to PostgreSQL interaction) and postgresql-9.1-901-1.jdbc4.jar driver. So how are you checking that it is NULL in your case?

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cayenne_tst_out_proc(IN i_n_sourceid int4, 
  OUT o_rc_source refcursor,
  OUT o_n_exitflag int4, 
  OUT o_s_exitmsg character varying
)
  RETURNS RECORD AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
   v_rc_source  refcursor := 'cur_ref';
BEGIN

   OPEN v_rc_source FOR
     SELECT * FROM artist;

    o_rc_source    := v_rc_source;    
    O_N_exitFlag   := 11;
    O_S_exitMsg    := 'Ok';
  END;

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE COST 100;
```

Cayenne mapping:

```
<procedure name="cayenne_tst_out_proc">
    <procedure-parameter name="i_n_sourceid" type="INTEGER" direction="in"/>
    <procedure-parameter name="o_rc_source" type="OTHER" direction="out"/>
    <procedure-parameter name="o_n_exitflag" type="INTEGER" direction="out"/>
    <procedure-parameter name="o_s_exitmsg" type="VARCHAR" direction="out"/>
</procedure>
```